# Google group word count for members?

Tags: python, xml, google-groups, google-groups-api

I have a google group, and I'd like to figure out how many words each member has posted. Is there a utility to do this?

If not, how can I get started writing a Python script to do this? Should I just grab XML from the group's feed and look through that? (I don't know anything about Python's handling of XML.)

On the Google groups site, I see XML feeds for recent posts, but not for all posts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like people have wanted a Groups API [since about 3 years ago](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=27). It looks like you may have to resort to page-scraping.